# C: struct initialisation of linked list resulting in access violation exception

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have a question regarding linked-lists/structs in C. I am trying to add vertices to a linked list and populate them with data.
Why do I get an access violation at `newHead->name = newVertexName` even though I assgined memory to newHead beforehand?

Code for context:

```
typedef struct Vertex Vertex;

typedef struct Vertex
{
    char name;
    Vertex *next;
} Vertex;

struct Vertex* AddVertex(Vertex* head, char newVertexName)
{
    Vertex* newHead = malloc(sizeof(Vertex));
    newHead->name = newVertexName; // Access violation occuring here
    newHead->next = head;
    return newHead;
}

int main()
{
    char s[100];
    const int nNrOfVerts = 27;
    Vertex* adjList[28];

    for(int i = 0; i <= nNrOfVerts; ++i)
    {
        adjList[i] = NULL;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= nNrOfVerts; ++i)
    {
        if(scanf("%s", s) == 1)
        {
            adjList[i] = AddVertex(adjList[i], s[i-1]);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

thank you!

Comment: Have you verified that `malloc` is succeeding on every call?

Comment: @Scott Hunter what exactly do you mean by verifing? The error occurs at the first execution of the statement above...

Comment: BTW `s[i-1]` --> `s[0]`

Comment: Verifying that malloc is succeeding means checking the result of calling malloc to make sure that it is not NULL. malloc will return NULL if it can't allocate the memory. So with Vertex* newHead = malloc(sizeof(Vertex)); NewHead will be NULL if malloc fails, and then newHead->name = newVertexName; will probably result in an access violation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to include files:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc/free */
#include <stdio.h>  /* for scanf */
```

It's fix your access violation.

Secondly, I think you have bug here:

```
adjList[i] = AddVertex(adjList[i], s[i-1]);
```

vs:

```
adjList[i] = AddVertex(adjList[i-1], s[i-1]);
```

Comment: The way it currently is, that'd be more like a prev rather than a next pointer ie. that's reverse connecting.